# How to hide the contents of a filter using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve this in css + html? I want that all the contents inside the filter is hidden when clicked on an icon.

[image]

[image]

How do we obtain this in css?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: You need at least minimum amount of JS on top of your HTML+CSS in order to handle click event. On this click event you would want to change the class for given HTML node betwenn "expanded" and "collapsed". Both of them should be styled properly in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You must do this with Jquery or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in pure HTML + CSS, with a little bit of trickery. The method involves using a checkbox's state to determine if the filter should be displayed or not. Here's a basic setup.

```
<div>
  <label for="filter-cat-1">Category 1</label>
  <input class="toggle-display" id="filter-cat-1" type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Next the CSS

```
.toggle-display {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-display:checked + ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Now what's actually happening here? As you can tell, we hide both the checkbox AND the `ul` element. However we add a style declaration which will only be applied to a `ul`, which is placed directly AFTER a CHECKED `.toggle-display` element. This means that as soon as our invisible checkbox is checked (which will happen once it's label is clicked) the `ul` will appear.